# Form validation needs callback

Tags: callback

I am validating with Javascript a changing password form. I want to validate, the user's current password with Ajax that is returning true or false. If it's true then continue checking next inputs. I think I need a callback, but I'm doing something wrong, because it's not waiting the Ajax result, it is going ahead. Where and how i have to place the callback? Thx so much!

I have a form:

```
<form id="pwdform" action="#" onSubmit="return validatePwdForm()" method="POST">
   <label>Current password</label>
   <label style="display:none">Your current password is wrong</label>
   <input type="password" id="currentpassword" name="currentpassword" value=""/>
        ...
</form>
```

I have the Javascript validation function:

```
function validatePwdForm(){
  // ... checking stuff ...
  checkPwd('givenpassword');//Ajax call (I have it working properly, returning true or false) ...
  //... If it's false, I want to stop checking other inputs
  //... more stuff ...
}
```

And Ajax call to check password with database:

```
function checkPwd(pwd){
   //...Ajax call ok and returns true or false
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for `validatePwdForm` and `checkPwd`?

Answer (score 0):

In your function `validatePwdForm()`, the data returned by the function `checkPwd()` is not assigned to any variable.Something like this:

```
var res=checkPwd(pswd);

if(res==true){

              //continue checking 

             } 
else { 

    //show error message

    }
```

Otherwise you can place remaining inputs in another function and call the function from ajax success function itself.

```
$.ajax(function(){
....
....
success:function(data){

if(data==true) separateFun();

else //show error message

}
});
```